# Объединение нескольких строк в одну VK-IO?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, пишу бота на NODE.JS, я получил ответ от vk-api но он идёт в таком формате:

```
STRING
STRING
STRING....
```

Мне нужно сделать так STRING, STRING, STRING

Comment: `result.split(/\n/).join(', ')`

Answer (score 0):

```
s = s.replace(/\r?\n/g, ", ")
```